# How to pass on parameters from one function with variable amount of parameters to another with variable amount of parameters in typescript?

Tags: typescript

This does not work

```
static myDebug(message: string, ...optionalParameters: any[]): void {
    // tslint:disable-next-line
    console.debug(message, optionalParameters);
}
```

it just writes lines like this

```
test myDebug this.url = Array(2), windowId = %d
```

instead of

```
test myDebug this.url = /myurl, windowId = 123
```

In C this cannot be done so I need to do it like this:

```
    va_start(Args, Message);
    vsnprintf_s(Buffer, sizeof(Buffer), _TRUNCATE, Format, Args);
    va_end(Args);
    CallTheFunction(Buffer);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to log the entries of the rest array rather than the rest array itself, spread it out:

```
static myDebug(message: string, ...optionalParameters: any[]): void {
    // tslint:disable-next-line
    console.debug(message, ...optionalParameters);
    // --------------------^^^
}
```

Spread syntax is, in many ways, the complement of rest syntax.

Using that, if you called `myDebug` like this:

```
myDebug("hi there", 1, 2, 3);
```

it would call `console.debug` like this (effectively):

```
console.debug(message, optionalParameters[0], optionalParameters[1], optionalParameters[2]);
```

Comment: thanks! This was the 1st thing I tried and VSCode told me that the syntax was wrong. Or so I thought because now I tried and it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this by using an object that has optional parameters, which will also give you nice autocompletion for all the options. Using `any` is risky because you could have typos, or pass arguments that are never used. I assume you use Typescript to get type safety.

```
interface OptionalParameters {
    name?:string
}

static myDebug(p: OptionalParameters): void {
    console.dir(p)
}
```

When calling myDebug you can pass an empty object, or an object that has the name parameter.

```
myDebug({})                              // ok
myDebug({name:"hello"})                  // ok
myDebug({name:"hello", test:"world"})    // test is not an option
```